# How to cancel Finder search via keyboard?

Tags: macos, finder

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to exit via keyboard a search I initiate in Finder <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>. I can search and see the results yet other that pressing the `x` with the mouse

[image]

which exits the search i cant figure out how to do the same with a keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your locale and how you started the search:

- If you started the search with no window open, it's simply <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> (which closes the window)
- If you started the search in an open window, it's <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> (US)(or e.g. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Ö</kbd> (German)) which goes one step back to the previous window. The shortcut is usually visible in the menubar of the Finder > Go > Back.

Comment: perfect! that solved the question.